# How to solve an integral equation in python?

Tags: python, scipy, equation, numerical-integration

I'm trying to solve this integral equation using Python:

[image]

where z ranges from 0 to 1.

The scipy.quad function only provides the numerical solution for a certain interval, but it doesn't provide the solution over the interval.

```
def f(z,Om,Ol): return 1./p.sqrt((1+z)**2 * (1+Om*z) - z*(2+z)*Ol)
quad(lambda r:f(r,Om,Ol),0,1)
(0.77142706642781111, 8.5645609096719596e-15)
```

But I don't know how to get a full vector in this interval, as you get when using scipy.odeint to solve a differential equation.

In the other hand, sympy.integrate can't do it. I get a stack overflow. Plus, I can't figure out how to substitute the symbols by a list,i.e.:

```
sy.integrate(x**2,x).subs(x,1)
1/3
sy.integrate(x**2,x).subs(x,[1,2])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

So the question is: does anyone know how to solve an integral equation using python?

Comment: Use numpy:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html

Comment: as you talk about an integral equation: What is the value you are looking for ? Do you want to get z1 for a given D_L ?

Comment: You have a z before the integral, is this an typo ?

Comment: I can't figure out how to use linalg to solve an integral equation.

Answer (score 4):

I understand that you want to solve a differential equation `dF/dz1 = f(z1, Om, Ol)` and want `F(z1)` at different locations.  If this is the case, then the [Ordinary Differential Equation (ODE) routines](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html#integrators-of-ode-systems) of SciPy are the way to go.  You might want to [check](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html#scipy.integrate.odeint) `odeint()`, in particular, as it can give you the values of your integral at locations that you specify.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm not trying to solve a differential equation, but to solve a integral equation. I've used odeint() routine in other cases and it works fine for me, but it's useful only for differential equations, I can't use it in this case.

Comment: @Illa Rivero Losada: Thanks.  Are you trying to have Python find an *analytical formula* for the integral?  "Solving an integral equation" in fact has a very specific meaning (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_equation), which does not appear to apply to your question.  If you are indeed looking for an analytical solution, a good place to ask this question would be mathoverflow.  The case ΩM = 0 is doable (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_irrational_functions), but I'm not sure about the general case…

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the z before the integral is a typo which should be z1, and you are looking for z1 given DL.

First you have to implement the right hand side (rhs):

```
def f(z,Om,Ol): 
        return 1./p.sqrt((1+z)**2 * (1+Om*z) - z*(2+z)*Ol)
def rhs(z1, Om, Ol, c, H0):
        return c/H0*(1+z1)*quad(lambda r:f(r, Om, Ol), 0, z1)[0]
```

Now you have to find a z0 such that rhs(z1, ...) = DL, which is the same as

```
rhs(z1, ...) - DL = 0
```

Which means that your problem is reduced to finding the zero (there is only one, because rhs is monotone in), of

```
f(z1) = rhs(z1, ...) - DL
```

Here you can apply many methods for root finding (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) from http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#root-finding

Answer (score 0):

In the sympy examples section at, http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/integrals.html, they show solutions to nearly identical problems.  Can you post your sympy code?

For scipy, did you try using a tuple, which is hashable, instead of a list?  e.g.:

```
sy.integrate(x**2,x).subs(x,(1,2,))
```

Comment: I've tried, but I got an error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'tuple' and 'Integer'

Answer (score 0):

I finally used the "quad" function with a for statement to solve my problem:

```
import pylab as p
import scipy as s
from scipy.integrate import odeint,quad

def Dl_lflrw(z,Om,Ol):
    c = 1.
    H0 = 1.
    y = []
    for i in z:
        y1 = (c/H0)*(1+i)*quad(lambda r:f(r,Om,Ol),0,i)[0]
        y.append(y1)
    return p.asarray(y)

def f(z,Om,Ol):
    return 1./p.sqrt((1+z)**2 * (1+Om*z) - z*(2+z)*Ol)
```

Thank you all for your ideas, they was really helpful.